# getting unsupported relations error in gorm one to many relation

Tags: database, go, grails-orm

I have two tables and want to find a row of first table(based on id) and all the matching rows of second table.

But I am getting this error again and again.

[image]
[image]

I tried multiple ways including

```
id:=c.Param("id")
var order models.Order
db.Find(&order,id)
db.Where("OrderId=?",id).Find(&order.OrderItems)
```

but in this the error was -

```
: Unknown column 'OrderId' in 'where clause'
m SELECT * FROM `order_items` WHERE OrderId=36 AND `order_items`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `order_items`.`id` LIMIT 1
2023/01/20 14:44:52 {{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 0 0 0 0}`
```

If somebody can help please help me

Comment: A typo - `OrderID` in the table versus `OrderId` in your query.